# How to pass multiple related parameters in GET request for "filter query parameter family" standards defined in in JSON:API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, json-api

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6.0 and i need to create an api endpoint that can handle two fix parameters that must be provided always and a list of optional filter parameters:

```
https://<host>/api/article/GetArticles?pageId=123&filterId=234&filter[category]=1,2&filter[author]=12&filter[year]=2023
```

as you can see the filter-types are specified in brackets. This is the [filter standard defined in JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering) which should be used. But how does the endpoint in the controller needs to be defined to support it?

This does not work, of course(`filter` is `null`):

```
[HttpGet("GetArticles")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IContent>> GetArticles(
    int pageId, 
    int filterId, 
    string? filter = null)
{
    // TODO ...
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dictionary for such mapping - `[FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string>? filter = null`:

```
[HttpGet("GetArticles")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetArticles(
    int pageId,
    int filterId, 
    [FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string>? filter = null)
{
    // TODO ...
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a great way. I was already creating a dictionary manually from `Request.Query` which would also work but is less elegant than this approach. Of course you still need to split the values since they can contain multiple filters per type. But that's an easy task.

Answer (score 2):

This is a minimal working example. Tested with this path in the Postman

```
/GetArticles?pageId=1&filterId=2&filter[category]=3&filter[author]=5
```

Notice that filter is dictionary because I'm sending key value pairs for filter property

```
[HttpGet("GetArticles")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IContent>> GetArticles(
    int pageId,
    int filterId, 
    [FromQuery] IDictionary<string, string>? filter)
{
    // TODO ...
    return Ok();
}
```

I think you can imagine now that you can do more than this.

Comment: Thanks, same way as Guru's so i upvoted, but he was a bit faster :)